# i try to write arm assembly code, but it makes core dumped error how can i resolve this?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to convert it into an ARM assembly code.

```
char input_strings[5][250] = 
{

"a.",

"I ",

"C oo.",

"ll",

"this"



};
```

it is c code.i try to write arm assembly as follow c code.
            this two dimension array address devided by 250 unit. so i have written to arm assembly,

```
        MOV r4,#1;  @ i=1
        MOV r5,#0;  @j=0
        MOV r6,#0;  @k=0
        MOV r7,#0;  @cnt=0
        LDRB r2,[r0,#0];  @load first string to origin
        LDRB r3,[r0,#0];  @to be stored next string to comp
        loop1:
        CMP r4,r1;  @compare i,num_of_string
        BEQ EXIT1;  @if equal goto EXIT1
        LDRB r3,[r3,#250]; @load next string   <-----------it make core dumped error
```

but this arm code made core dumped error. also it's not total code. it is just front part.
            how can i resolve this core dumped error problem??

Comment: r0 is input_string two dimension array. it receive as function parameter.

Comment: What do you reckon the chances are of the character in `r3` _also_ being a valid memory address?

Comment: which specific arch is that? According to the [arm documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHDGFEG.html), the meaning of the instruction differs depending on the CPU model.